# Forwarding my client appreciation notes to a new manager

Tags: professionalism, clients, feedback, consultants

My present manager is moving to a different team at the end of the month. I have received a few client appreciation notes last week.

What is more professional? Should I assume that my outgoing manager will give feedback or is it OK for me to forward them to my new manager copying the departing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends completely on what stage the handover is at. If your manager is still in operational control and the new one has only been announced, then just send it to your old one. If they're now job sharing then send it both.

To put it another way, don't let the fact you're self promoting cloud the issue. Who would you email right now if there was a problem?

Comment: I agree with this though, I think I would add something about saving all the kudos from before the manager started and forwarding them just prior to the next performance review with a note that just in case you were not aware of these.

Comment: Yes still old manager is in operational control., he seems not forwarding appreciation mails.,so new manager are not aware of them

Answer (score 1):

Well done getting notes of appreciation from clients!

Please keep in mind that these testimonials are not just about you: They are about your team and your company. They are a very valuable business asset.

Why?

- For one thing they probably explain what you did that helped the client. Your team can use that information to help improve what you all do for every client.
- They also can be used, judiciously, to help your marketing and sales people strengthen the company's market position and improve sales materials.

There's probably only one other kind of note from a client that's MORE valuable, and that is a well-reasoned complaint.

So, YES, let both your outgoing and incoming manager know about these client appreciations.  You, or your manager, should also inform the sales team about them.

If your managers are wise, they will decide that the new one will write a note back to the customer saying something like this: 'Thank you for letting me know how my new team member has helped you. I'm delighted to be working with this person and this team, and I invite you to contact me at any time.'

Comment: It is not really the developers role to inform sales of kudos in most companies.  Many times these types of accolades are from internal customers and marketing is not really involved.